# Image Processing: The result of Sobel filter turns out to be gray instead of black and white?

Tags: c#, image-processing, sobel

I'm trying to implement a Sobel filter myself.

The result I obtained looks very similar to this (gray):

[image]

But not like this (black & white with gradient):

[image]

I had tried using threshold but it feels not right:

[image]

Is there any method that I can turn the grayscale to the **black&white with gradient** result?

---

The following are the steps I use to filter an image in C#:

1. Convert a bitmap from a file (already in grayscale)
2. Convolute each pixel with a Sobel kernel (ex. horizontal)

   ```
   private static float[][] Sobel3x3Kernel_Horizontal() {
   ```

   `return new float[][] {
           new float[]{ 1, 2, 1},
           new float[]{ 0, 0, 0 },
           new float[]{ -1, -2, -1}
       };

   }`
3. Re-map all values to let them fall within the range 0~255 (otherwise there will be negative values or values larger than 255, which can't be used to do Bitmap.SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
4. Output the bitmap result (grayscale)

Comment: set all negative values to zero

Comment: see example  https://github.com/techmn/ImageProcessing

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
However before doing the (Step 3.) "Re-map" step, the pixel values obtained after the convolution falls within range -565 ~ 616..
I can set all negative values to zero, but what can I do with those larger than 0 to obtain **black&white with gradient** result?

Comment: just one if else like `if (pixel > 255) { pixel = 255; } else if(pixel < 0) { pixel = 0; }`

Comment: Thanks again...
Unfortunately, I did what you say
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oMk9CDLlwWJOvUkD8SctLR7azFq3aqUf/view?usp=sharing
However the result still remains the same (in grayscale)...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vNxaAvGURFWo4gISfvNs7sDBpAjQ_PN3/view?usp=sharing
 
Is there something wrong with this line of code in the first picture? 
c = Color.FromArgb(255, value, value, value);

Comment: you are not applying filter in that code. please check example here  https://github.com/techmn/ImageProcessing/blob/master/BasicImageProcessing/BasicImageProcessing/ImageOperation.cs

Comment: No, this is really bad advice! Don’t throw away all negative gradients! The black and white image shown in Wikipedia is the gradient magnitude, not the x-gradient.

Comment: @crisLuengo is right... the gradient magnitude should be in black & white.
It turns out that it's my third step that causes the grayscale result to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replicate that image you linked from Wikipedia, follow these steps:

1. Compute the convolution with the Sobel kernel to obtain the x derivative `dx`.
2. Compute another convolution to obtain the y derivative `dy` (transpose the kernel).
3. These two derivatives together form the gradient (a vector value at each pixel). Determine the magnitude by computing `sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)`. `^2` here indicates square.
4. Threshold the result if you want a pure black-and-white result, otherwise scale the result by multiplying it by some value so that the displayed image looks good to you.

Note that what you call the **"grayscale image problem"** is simply the mapping (your 3<sup>rd</sup> step) of 0 values to a middle-grey, so that negative values can be shown. This is a correct way of displaying a derivative, as otherwise the negative values would be clipped and hence not visible. These negative values are an important part of the derivative. But this mapping should *only* be used for display, further computations should always be done on the original values.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question!
So after your third step I got the magnitude, and I set an if-else statement (not for x-gradient nor y-gradient, but for magnitude)`if(magnitude > 255){magnitude = 255;} else if(magnitude < 0){magnitude = 0;}` to discard negative values and values larger than 255, and now I finally have the wonderful result!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lfhJp-ynuBmuh9XC55mJ_Ig_8fCEhy0O/view

I hope my if-else statement for regulating the range of magnitude is appropriate here.

Comment: So it's **my third step** (re-map) that causes the grayscale image problem...
Otherwise, just like you said, the gradient magnitude image should originally be in black & white.

Comment: The derivatives have negative values, the gradient magnitude doesn’t. You can scale the gradient magnitude image by multiplying it by `255/max`, where `max` is the largest value. You can also clip as you are doing, but you lose information there. What you call “grayscale image problem” is simply the mapping of 0 values to a middle-grey, so that negative values can be shown. That is perfectly valid, but only for display, further computations should always be done on the original values, not the scaled ones.

Comment: When I compare your result to the image in Wikipedia I conclude that you are not computing the magnitude correctly. Make sure you take the sum of squares of the two components, not directly their sum. You should see no negative values, and all 4 edges of the bricks should have the same response —in your result only the right and bottom edges have a response, the other two likely had a negative response that you set to zero.

Comment: Or maybe you are throwing away negative values in `dx` and `dy`. Don’t do that. Store those in a signed integer type (or float type) array

Comment: Thank you, Cris! Your explanation above not only clarify the idea of sobel filter, but also points out my mistakes! I surely will take a look at my buggy-code and fix my problem once again. :)